# Non-Traditional Definition of Dual Basis in $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

From an undergraduate book on Harmonic Analysis:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

**Question 1:** What is the relationship between this description of a "dual basis" and [this more traditional one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis)?

**Question 2:** To check my understanding, let $N = 2$ and consider the basis $\{(2, 0), (0, 2i) \}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Is its dual basis $\{1/2,0), (0, i/2)\}$ in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same, under the canonical identification of $\mathbb C^N $ with its dual. The duality consists of writing every functional as $v\longmapsto \langle v,w\rangle $.

So from the formula you have $$\langle w_k,v_j\rangle=\delta_{k,j}, $$ which makes $w_1,\ldots, w_N $ the dual basis.

To your second question: yes.

Comment: Did you mean $v \mapsto \langle w, v \rangle$?

Comment: No. With the usual definition  $\langle x,y\rangle=y^*x $, your map would be conjugate linear, so not an element of the dual.